# unknown target when doing a fly sync

Tags: concourse

I have spun up a VM and I am trying to login to my concourse server with the following:

```
Christoher:pipeline christopher$ fly --target chris login --team-name chris --concourse-url http://ld4370.mycompany.com
```

Then, I am receiving this message:

```
WARNING:

fly version (2.5.0) is out of sync with the target (2.4.0). to sync up, run the following:

fly -t chris sync
```

However, when I do the following, I get this issue:

```
Christoher:pipeline christopher$ fly -t chris sync
error: unknown target: chris
```

At first, I had an older version of fly. So I deleted fly in my `/usr/local/bin` directory and then downloaded the latest. Now I am ahead of the concourse version that I installed on my VM. I have taken a look at the [fly documentation](https://concourse.ci/fly-cli.html) but have not figured out how to get around this.

Answer (score 2):

As an immediate fix to your problem, you can download any version of fly from github https://github.com/concourse/concourse/releases.

Comment: Thanks! Removing `fly` from `/usr/local/bin` and downloading the version I need works.

Answer (score 0):

Download/ update concourse and fly version 4 and below 4 Hi go to this website basically you need to install the relevant version https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/f20afd45a24ab3f88d01b2049ce7744f

for example:
copy this command

curl -Lo fly https://github.com/concourse/concourse/releases/download/2.5.0/fly_darwin_amd64 && chmod +x fly && mv fly /usr/local/bin/

and changed the version v2.6.0 to v2.5.0 past it in the terminal and same goes for the below :

curl -Lo concourse 
https://github.com/concourse/concourse/releases/download/v2.4.0/concourse_darwin_amd64 && chmod +x concourse && mv concourse /usr/local/bin

and it should work. 
I had similar problem i wanted install the v4.2.2 and it worked. the idea is the get the same version

Answer (score 0):

Download concourse & fly new version 5.0.0 on Mac do the following:

Download the latest version from concourse website https://mockersf.github.io/docs/download.html

then open finder press CMD + Shift + . 
it will make all your hidden files visible temporarily open your user/local/bin folder then drag the new version of concourse to the bin and click replace
do the same for the fly and now go in command line press fly --version and you should see the new version